# Guidance on dependency injection, or am I off base?

Tags: dependency-injection, module

Sort of a newbie question...

I am adding some billing information to an existing application in order to automate invoicing. We have determined that there are 4 distinct billing mechanisms that our company uses. (Different clients are billed differently, depending on contract.) It's also possible that additional billing mechanisms may come into play. I want to develop it in a way that wouldn't require recompiling and redistribution if a new billing mechanism develops or even if there is a change to an existing one. Basically, I would prefer to just push a new or updated "billing module" and the system would recognize it.

I figure the billing modules would contain xaml defining the interface necessary to collect the data specific to one mechanism, as well as the algorithms used to determine invoice amounts. It's a WPF/MVVM application, if that matters.

Is this what dependency injection is for or is this a different coding paradigm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency Injection is a way to construct objects that need other objects to function. If object A needs objects B and C, and Object C needs Object D, then B,C and D are "dependencies" of A.

Also object B, C, D and E may come in various flavours and may be configured differently.

Dependency Injection(DI), relies on B, C, D and E being constructed outside the client object. References to those objects are passed to the Client object via the Client's constructor (usually).

More advanced systems (such as frameworks) use special factory object called "DI Containers" or sometimes "Service Locators" to create the objects and their dependencies. The end product is still injected as above into the Client object.

That sounds a bit like what you are doing .. except that the system needs to know in advance about the objects its it creating! In your case you are inventing new objects - billing systems - , that your system may not yet know about.

You may need to consider other mechanisms such a "plugin" system like you see for browsers, where new functionality can be added in-situ. Often new functionality in the Microsoft is added by adding new DLL's .. or even providing different versions of DLLs that implement different versions of your billing system as in your example.

In short DI is too low level a concept to achieve what you need alone, although you may use DI as part of the solution.

Finally DI is an concept of Object Programming in general and not limited to any particular language or framework.